# C# .Net How to auto separate Textbox input with comma

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to allow the following sequence on my textbox.

```
e.g. 
    09123456789
e.g.
    09123456789,09123456789
e.g.
    09123456789,09123456789,09506724016
```

The input should start with `09` followed by the next nine numbers.
If more than eleven is input, then a comma should automatically add at the end then it should start again with `09` followed by the next nine numbers.

I have this regex `^(09)\\d{9}` that accepts only the first sequence, but I don't how to apply the whole sequence into my Textbox.

```
private void phone_number_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //validate the textbot to allow only the sequence.
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far, and what exactly you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex accepts only the first sequence because it contains a start-of-input character `^`. If you want to detect that it's time to add a comma use `09\\d{9}$` instead. Maybe you could prefill the 09 for the user too

If you want to also do something like turn the back color red if the entry isn't a match, consider checking that the textbox complied with logic like:

```
private Regex _phNum = new Regex(@"^09\d{9}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

And then a text changed like:

```
tb.BackColor = tb.Text.Split(',').All(_phNum.IsMatch) ? Color.White : Color.Red;
```